# Writing Java/Maven integration tests using webservice database and jms

Tags: java, web-services, maven, jenkins, integration-testing

I'm maintaining a Java Enterprise Application that exposes a few webservices and interacts with a few JMS queues and a database.

I've got most of the code unit tested and I thought all was good until in a refactoring I moved a class in another package and that changed a namespace in my webservice without me noticing and breaking all clients.
An Integration Test would have caught that, so I'm trying to write one.

The application is deployed on JBoss EAP 6.4, how can I make a webservice call in my `mvn verify` step?
What about JMS Queues? They are configured on the Application Server.
Is the application supposed to be already deployed?
Am I supposed to deploy the application with maven to a JBoss installation before the `verify` step or start an embedded webserver?

Most of the docs around are confusing to me and often I see suggestion to mock stuff, which is not integration testing (and I already do in Unit tests).

Someone told me "just use Jenkins" and I read the docs, installed it and still don't understand how that is supposed to help me write integration tests since all it does is run `mvn verify` anyway.

Answer (score 1):

This topic and is too broad, there might be many different correct answers for this question and will depend a lot on the technologies you're using, so I'll focus first in this part only:

> that changed a namespace in my webservice without me noticing and
>   breaking all clients

You can create unit tests for endpoints too, I do that all the time with `spring-boot`. For example, the code below starts the application, runs the `testEndpoint()` test and shuts down the application right after.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = {MyApplication.class})
@WebAppConfiguration
@IntegrationTest("server.port:0")
public class MyControllerTest {

    @Value("${local.server.port}")
    private int port;

    @Test
    public void testEndpoint() {
        String endpointUrl = "http://localhost:" + port;
        // make a HTTP request here to test the endpoint
    }
}
```

I believe this can be done with any `spring-mvc` application, but the code would be a bit different and not as easy as with `spring-boot`.

Although this would usually catch most bugs in endpoints, it doesn't eliminate the need of integration tests against a deployed project.

So focusing on the bigger picture now, if you want to create end-to-end tests, including WebServices, JMS queues and databases, I suggest creating a separate project with tests only, probably using Cucumber or something similar. This project should be triggered in Jenkins (or any other CI tool) whenever needed (e.g. before a deployment, every hour, every commit and/or every night) and it will require that all applications are already deployed.

Alternatively, you could have Jenkins deploy an application and run integration tests only against this one application. In this case the tests will depend on all other applications to be already deployed.